# WPF this.NavigationService.Navigate

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

I am learning a WPF tutorial from Microsoft website which is following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application#add-code-to-handle-events

I am getting the following error from my code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //View Expense Report
    ExpenseReportPage expenseReportPage = new ExpenseReportPage(); //Line 1
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(expenseReportPage); // Line 2
}
```

Line 2 in above code gives following error for NavigationService:

> 'invalid-global-code' does not contain a definition for
>   'NavigationService' and no accessible extention method
>   'NavigationService' accepting the first argument of type '' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

I have added the using System.Windows.Navigation;
I think the problem is coming from 'this' part of this.NavigationService.Navigate(expenseReportPage);

Comment: Can't see the error in your question.

Comment: Did you change your main window to a navigation window? The default window doesn't have a navigation property.

Comment: Yes i changed the main window to navigationwindow. it still does not work. it does not pick up 'this' when referring to NavigationService.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Window` element to a `NavigationWindow` element, or add a `Frame` element to your window and access its `NavigationService` property:

```
frame.NavigationService.Navigate(expenseReportPage); // Line 2
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window ...>
    <Frame x:Name="frame" />
</Window>
```

Comment: I have changed the Window element to NavigationWindow as instructed in the tutorial it still does not work. I can not add Frame attribute to NavigationWindow element as that option is not available. Please suggest.

Comment: FIXED: I had this.NavigationService... block outside NavigationWindow class in code-behind. I moved the block inside this class and it worked.

Comment: You can  add a `Frame` element to a window as I demonstrated in my answer. If you have a `NavigationWindow`, you shouldn't add a `Frame`.